# How to do partition by in sql for the below example

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, amazon-redshift, window-functions

I have a table as follows:

```
  EmpID   | Type | timestamp |         | block_id
    1     |  'R' | 2018-04-15 01:13:15 | 1234
    1     |  'P' | 2018-04-15 05:13:15
    1     |  'P' | 2018-04-15 05:13:15
    1     |  'P' | 2018-04-15 05:13:15
    1     |  'D' | 2018-04-15 07:13:15
    1     |  'D' | 2018-04-15 08:13:15
    1     |  'D' | 2018-04-15 10:13:15
    1     |  'R' | 2018-04-15 13:13:00 | 3453
    1     |  'P' | 2018-04-15 13:15:15
    1     |  'P' | 2018-04-15 13:15:15
    1     |  'P' | 2018-04-15 13:15:15
    1     |  'D' | 2018-04-15 14:13:00
    1     |  'D' | 2018-04-15 15:13:00
    1     |  'D' | 2018-04-15 16:13:37
    2     |  'R' | 2018-04-15 04:15:00 | 0986
    2     |  'P' | 2018-04-15 04:20:00
    2     |  'D' | 2018-04-15 05:11:33
```

And I'm trying to get an output as follows:

```
EmpID  | begin_timestamp     | end_timestamp      | block_id | P_count | D_count
1      | 2018-04-15 01:13:15 |2018-04-15 10:13:15 | 1234    | 3       | 3
1      | 2018-04-15 13:13:00 | 2018-04-15 16:13:37| 3453    | 3       | 3
2      | 2018-04-15 04:15:00 | 2018-04-15 05:11:33| 0986    | 1       | 1
```

i.e., these are sort of blocks and each empId can have multiple blocks. So from the above sample table, empID `'1'` has 2 blocks (beginning from row 1 to row 7), and 2nd block from row 8 to row 14; empID `2` has 1 block, row 14 to row 16.

How do I get the required output?? I'm stuck!! Please help.

Also, the table isn't ordered and is shown above like that only for explanation.

UPDATE: Sorry, I didn't mention earlier, the block_id has alphanumeric values and not just numeric values. block_id could be 'AX2#2', '123R2*',... anything random values.

Comment: show us your query?

Comment: try to use group by

Comment: On a phone do can't really try any code, but you could try looking at a sub-query to assign those blocks to all of the dates < next block number. Then min, max on timestamp and group by block

Comment: What's your SQL server version?

Answer (score 1):

Use `group by` clause with *conditional* aggregation for counts

```
select EmpID, min(timestamp) as begin_timestamp,
              max(timestamp) as end_timestamp, new_block_id as block_id,
              sum(case when Type = 'P' then 1 else 0 end) as P_count,
              sum(case when Type = 'D' then 1 else 0 end) as D_count
from table t
group by EmpID, block_id;
```

**EDIT :** as for **MtwStark** i have added other version if block_id is `null` or `blank`

```
select EmpID, min(timestamp) as begin_timestamp,
              max(timestamp) as end_timestamp, block_id,
              sum(case when Type = 'P' then 1 else 0 end) as P_count,
              sum(case when Type = 'D' then 1 else 0 end) as D_count
from (select *,
           sum(block_id) over (partition by empid order by timestamp) as new_block_id
      from table)t
group by EmpID, new_block_id;
```

Comment: does not work, block_id = null is not a new group, rows with block_id = null shoud be counted in correct group

Comment: @MtwStark... This assumes `block_id` doesn't have `null`.

Comment: same problem for `block_id = ''` as you see input data `block_id` have value only for 1st row of block

Comment: @MtwStark.. well this was always assumed that the block_id was always in well formed. Btw, added with other version.

Comment: @YogeshSharma Sorry my bad, block_id doesn't necessary have only numeric values, it is alphanumeric.

Comment: @Anjali.. What kind of data in `block_id` you have, or edit the question.

Comment: @YogeshSharma block_id could be 'AX2#2', '123R2*',... anything. They are random values.

Answer (score 1):

Try Like This...

```
     ;WITH CTE
     AS
    (
        SELECT  1   AS RowNo,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Mytable) AS RowCnt,
        EmpID,
        Type,
        timestamp,
        block_id,
        CASE WHEN Type = 'P' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS P_count,
        CASE WHEN Type = 'D' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS D_count
FROM    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY EmpID) AS ID,* FROM Mytable) t
WHERE   t.ID    =   1

UNION ALL

SELECT  CTE.RowNo+1,
        CTE.RowCnt - 1,
        t1.EmpID,
        t1.Type,
        t1.timestamp,
        CASE WHEN t1.block_id IS NULL THEN CTE.block_id ELSE t1.block_id END 
        AS block_id,
        CASE WHEN t1.Type = 'P' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS P_count,
        CASE WHEN t1.Type = 'D' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS D_count
FROM    CTE
JOIN    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY EmpID) AS ID,* FROM Mytable) t1
    ON  (1  =   1)
WHERE   t1.ID   =   CTE.RowNo+1
    AND CTE.RowCnt  <>  0
  )

  SELECT EmpID,MIN(timestamp)  begin_timestamp,MAX(timestamp) 
        end_timestamp,block_id,SUM(P_count) P_count,SUM(D_count) D_count
   FROM CTE
   GROUP BY EmpID,block_id
   ORDER BY EmpID
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error: Invalid operation: relation "cte" does not exist;

Comment: Also can we avoid using UNION ALL here? Since the table is really huge.

Answer (score 0):

This query will work on SQL Server 2012+. For older version change inner query to self join

```
select
    EmpID, begin_timestamp = min([timestamp]), end_timestamp = max([timestamp])
    , block_id = max(block_id), P_count = sum(iif([Type] = 'P', 1, 0))
    , D_count = sum(iif([Type] = 'D', 1, 0))
from (
    select
        *, grp = sum(block_id) over (partition by EmpID order by [timestamp])
    from
        myTable
) t
group by EmpID, grp
```

Answer (score 0):

Conditional aggregation is a very good option, this version is almost the same already published but with a (very) little optimization on `block_id`

```
select EmpID, begin_timestamp = min([timestamp]), end_timestamp = max([timestamp]), block_id, P_count = sum(iif([Type] = 'P', 1, 0)), D_count = sum(iif([Type] = 'D', 1, 0))
from (
    select EmpID, Type, timestamp, max(block_id) over (partition by EmpID order by [timestamp]) block_id  from d
) d
group by EmpID, block_id
order by EmpID, block_id
```

Only for demonstration purpose, you can consider also `PIVOT` solution:

```
select EmpID, block_id, MIN(timestamp) begin_timestamp, MAX(timestamp) end_timestamp, SUM(D) D, SUM(P) P
from (
    select *
    from (
        select EmpID, Type, block_id, [timestamp]
        from (
            select EmpID, Type, timestamp, max(block_id) over (partition by EmpID order by [timestamp]) block_id from d
        ) t
    ) g
    pivot (count(type) for type in (D,P)) p
) c
group by EmpID, block_id
order by EmpID, block_id
```

**EDIT**

I have considered `block_id` alphanumeric instead of numeric because I have noticed the leading zero in one of them. This is the reason to use only `MAX` instead of `SUM` + `MAX`.

`MAX` works both for numeric and alpha, `SUM` works only for numeric values. Also you don't need the second aggregation on this field.

The only real problem here is the temporal order of rows, if two blocks of the same `EmpID` can overlap, AND `block_id` has value only on 1st row (type 'R') of each block, you have a really big problem because you have not informations to use to assign type 'D' and 'P' rows following the 2nd row of type 'R'.
**In this case, sorry, no way to solve your problem**.

If we can assure blocks are not overlapping OR `block_id` has value in all rows, the `max(block_id) over (partition by EmpID order by [timestamp])` will do the job.

In redshift you should use `UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING` instead of `CURRENT ROW`

Comment: Oh by the way, I did have to change a line in your query to : max(route_details_route_id) over (partition by execution_id order by timestamp rows BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) since I'm on redshift. Not sure if that would affect.

Comment: I just checked on the bigger dataset and it is not giving accurate results. I think the reason is that block_id are random alphanumeric values and doing max is not giving the result.

Comment: `MAX()` can not be the problem, it works fine with alphanumeric values. If you want help, you should extract some data with problems and then post them, so I can check. The only problem can be with overlapping of periods. also, check `UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING` instead of `CURRENT ROW`